# WSO2: How admin can generate user access token without user password

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to implement OTA (one time access) using WSO2 (IS 5.7.0, AM 2.5.0, EI 6.4.0), and I need to find a way to generate user access token.

I have tried:

- using admin service for password recovery. Disadvantage is email template is bound to password reset, but OTA is not a password reset scenario, so using password recovery email template will be spoiled.
- find admin service that generate user access token, but nothing was found
- find WSO2 extension\plugin, but nothing corresponding was found
- using OTP, but met an error like this: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/1860

Answer (score 1):

Even admins are not allowed to generate tokens for a user without their consent.

For one-time password, this should work.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Email+OTP

Comment: Is there any way to implement OTA by redirecting user from email to some url? I want to implement scenario when user follows link from email, and automatically logins in web application.

Comment: I have tried OTP, but met error with user account lock. User get email with OPT, but could not login, because of error
`System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION`. 
After this error i found that user account is locked (account locked user claim), and when i tried to unlock (set user claim account locked to false in mgt console or using admin service: setUserClaimValues or unlockUserAccount) and got error:
`Cannot unlock account, IdentityMgtEventListener is not enabled.`
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Ensure that the "IdentityMgtEventListener" with the orderId=50 is set to false and the "IdentityMgtEventListener" with the orderId=95 is set to true in the <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file.

Comment: These values were set initially (as mentioned in instruction https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Password+Recovery), but i checked them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom grant handler, to authenticate user, not via password, but using something he has unique(mobile no, email, etc) as per your requirement and generates an access token from that grant.

You can easily do a token call to WSO2 Identity Server through your custom grant and get the access token.

You can check out for more details in [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this way, but I try to avoid developing WSO2 extensions.

Comment: In the standard Oauth2 spec, you can not get user access tokens without a password or user consent.

Comment: I ll try to solve problem this way: create LDAP "ota-code" attribute and corresponding user claim ; create API in EI with handlers (using sequences):
"send ota-code": writes "ota-code" to user "ota-code" claim, and sends email with link that contains ota-code ; "process OTA-link": checks user OTA code, reset user password using admin service, generates access-token. How do you think - is this way enough correct?